# How to include all lib folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, require, environment, class-extensions

I want to extend core Array class with simple method:

```
class Array
  def to_hash
    result = Hash.new
    self.each { |a| result[a] = '' }
    result
  end
end
```

I put array.rb into lib/core_ext and tried to require it in application.rb by

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

But still get `undefined method 'to_hash' for ["var1", "var2", "var3"]:Array` if tried to use it in model method. Of course I rebooted the server after code changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once way you can do this is by adding the following to one of the files in `config/initializers`

```
require 'core_ext/array`
```

All your `autoload_paths` config value does is make the paths available for when the classes/files are requested. In my app I might have some file structure as follows

```
- lib/
  |
  |- deefour.rb
  |- deefour/
     |
     |- core_ext.rb
```

In my `deefour.rb` I have

```
require 'deefour/core_ext'
```

and inside `config/initializers` I have a `deefour.rb` file containing simply

```
require 'deefour'
```

The only way the autoload config value you set will cause Rails to look auto load `lib/deefour/core_ext.rb` is if you had some call to a class `Deefour::CoreExt` that existed in that file. This is why my `require 'deefour'` line in the initializer knows to autoload the `lib/deefour.rb` file.

The explicit `require 'deefour/core_ext'` in `lib/deefour.rb` serves the same purpose, since it too does not follow the standard class-name-to-directory mapping Ruby/Rails will expect.

Comment: Is it correct way to create a special file with require in initializers?

Comment: Yes, it's correct when you're trying to load a file from `lib/` that doesn't follow the typical class-name-to-directory mapping Ruby/Rails will expect

Comment: Can you show correct variant according standard class-name-to-directory convention?

Comment: You can't really do it with monkey patches. If I called some class method `Deefour::User::Manager.create!`, Ruby/Rails would find it's way to `lib/deefour/user/manager.rb` for the `Manager` class nested inside the `Deefour::User` namespace. You can't really do this with a monkey patch on the ruby core; thus the `require` lines.