# Rails4 where should I put my own extensions for existing library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created modules to add some extra functions to the existing libraries, which include both ruby built-in library and third party library (like String, Hash, ActiveModel and Nokogiri).

such as

```
# extension for ExistingClass
module SomeExtension
  def extra_method
    ... 
  end
end

ExistingClass.send(:include, SomeExtension::extra_method)
```

Where is the best location to put them in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably `lib`.

`lib/core_ext` can contain extensions for standard functions, and vendor-named directories under `lib` for others.

`config/initializers` is another commonly used location.

I'd recommend spending time looking at other projects to find what seems most common and works best for you.

Some links that may be of interest:

- [In Ruby on Rails, to extend the String class, where should the code be put in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654517/in-ruby-on-rails-to-extend-the-string-class-where-should-the-code-be-put-in)
- [How to include all lib folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593670/how-to-include-all-lib-folder)
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#extending-core-classes

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna take a look at links you suggest